# Javascript display none doesn't work while cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Live site- http://www.uposonghar.com/test/test_popup.html

I add JavaScript cookie with that popup so if anyone click on "Click Here if don't want to see this Again!" button then cookie will be stored, if cookie is stored then popup will not appear for him/her.

Once i click on that button cookie stored successfully, popup(id-myModal) disappear but popup bg/overlay(id- reveal-modal-bg) appears. i add that code but that doesn't work-

```
if(getCookie('abc')=="def" && document.getElementById('myModal'))
   document.getElementById('myModal').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('reveal-modal-bg').style.display="none";
```

There is a css on js page, maybe that overwrite my `display:none` as `display:block`- http://www.uposonghar.com/test/jquery.reveal.js

Code of js page-

```
if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                    unlockModal()               
                }
```

Full code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          }
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_value = null;
          }
        else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
        c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
        }


        if(getCookie('abc')=="def" && document.getElementById('myModal'))
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('reveal-modal-bg').style.display="none";
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try my answer? I have just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the javascript in jquery.reveal.js to

```
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop" && getCookie('abc')!="def") {
                    modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                }
                if(options.animation == "fade" && getCookie('abc')!="def") {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                } 
                if(options.animation == "none" && getCookie('abc')!="def" ) {
                            modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                            modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                            unlockModal()               
                }
```

Comment: A direct style setting on an object overrides a CSS stylesheet, no matter the load order of the style sheet.

Comment: The javascript in the page is making the direct style to display block. That is why we need to make it 'none' in onLoad.

Comment: Please add it to all cases. I am not sure whether your options.animation is "none" or "fade"